# Calculate time in a state by value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that contains time series data and I want to get the total time in a state by value.

The table looks like:

```
+----------------+---------------------+---------------+------------+
|             id | status_update_time  | current_state | last state |
+----------------+---------------------+---------------+------------+
|            248 | 2017-02-17 05:00:00 |             1 |          0 |
|            248 | 2017-02-17 02:00:00 |             0 |          1 |
|            248 | 2017-02-17 01:00:00 |             1 |          0 |
|            250 | 2017-02-17 06:00:00 |             0 |          1 |
|            250 | 2017-02-17 05:00:00 |             1 |          0 |
|            252 | 2017-02-17 06:00:00 |             0 |          2 |
|            252 | 2017-02-17 03:00:00 |             2 |          0 |
|            254 | 2017-02-17 03:00:00 |             0 |          1 |
|            254 | 2017-02-17 02:00:00 |             1 |          0 |
|            254 | 2017-02-17 01:00:00 |             0 |          1 |
|            254 | 2017-02-17 00:00:00 |             1 |          2 |
+----------------+---------------------+---------------+------------+
```

The expected output I'd like is:

```
+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
|             id | state               | time_in_seconds|          
+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
|            248 | 0                   |          10800 |
|            248 | 1                   |           3600 |
|            250 | 1                   |           3600 |
|            252 | 2                   |          10800 |
|            254 | 0                   |           7200 |
|            254 | 1                   |           7200 |
+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

EDIT: I have not been able to generate the second table, but I would like to.

The logic to make the second table would be id 248 was at state 1 for a total of 3600 seconds and at state 0 for a total of 10800 seconds. This is because from 2017-02-17 01:00:00 to 2017-02-17 02:00:00 it was in a 1 state, then from 2017-02-17 02:00:00 to 2017-02-17 05:00:00 it was in a 0 state, before changing to a one state.

Comment: can you add more details about how you are deriving the expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the expected output. This table has tens of thousands of rows so I need a query that can add up all the time at a state for each id. There's only three states, but not every id will have been in all three.

Comment: window functions problem - islands and gaps

Comment: @cflinspach How is the table magically transformed from the first table to second table???  We are not magicians.  You'll have describe to us how that happen!!!

Comment: @eric I just typed out the second table. I edited the question but I'm trying to get the second table and typed it as an example.

Comment: @cflinspach You will have to tell us the logic of turning the first table into the second table.

Comment: You've now been asked the same thing 4 times. Maybe have a coffee and think about what information people are trying to extract from you.

Comment: @strawberry I'm trying to answer it but don't understand the question. I'm trying to add up all the time each id has at a given state. If an id was state 1 from one time to another the the answer would be the timediff of the two times. Since there's an unknown number of rows I don't know how to calculate a running total from the timediff's.

Comment: Your last edit has improved things somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, cur_state, SUM(duration) as total_time
FROM (
  SELECT id, cur_state,
  (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MIN(InnerTable.status_update_time), OuterTable.status_update_time)) FROM t as InnerTable
  WHERE
   InnerTable.last_state = OuterTable.cur_state
   AND
   InnerTable.status_update_time > OuterTable.status_update_time
   AND
   InnerTable.id = OuterTable.id
  ) duration
  FROM t as OuterTable
) anyName
WHERE duration IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, cur_state
```

You can check it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a8439/38